# Is it a good practice to nest try-with-resources statement in order to wrap DataOutputStream Instance in it?

Tags: java, android, io, try-catch, code-structure

Here is my question, should I be coding with out a nested try or should I be coding without try-with-resources statement to wrap DataOutputStream ? Or is there a better solution for this? I would really appreciate your help.

I am recently learning to write a java socket client on android with Android Studio.

> Inspection told me to initialize a socket with try statement, which I did.

```
public static String sendSocket(String newText) {
    final int timeout = 5000;
    try (Socket soc = new Socket()){
        final InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.3", 6101);
        soc.connect(address, timeout);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "socket done";
}
```

then I haven't atcually send my "newText", so I decided to add little more thing do it.Here is what I wrote after doing some research.

```
    public static String sendSocket(String newText) {
    final int timeout = 5000;
    try (Socket soc = new Socket()){
        final InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.3", 6101);
        soc.connect(address, timeout);
        if (!newText.isEmpty()) {
            final byte[] buffer = newText.getBytes("UTF-8");
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            dos.writeBytes("\n");
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "socket done";
}
```

> But then Inspection told that DataOutputStream should be use with a try-with-resources statement, I did what it asking again, code block end up like this

```
public static String sendSocket(String newText) {
    final int timeout = 5000;
    try (Socket soc = new Socket()){
        final InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.3", 6101);
        soc.connect(address, timeout);
        if (!newText.isEmpty()) {
            final byte[] buffer = newText.getBytes("UTF-8");
            try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream())) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                dos.writeBytes("\n");
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "socket done";
}
```

> But then inspection was still not satisfied, telling me that I shouldn't write nested try which may result to be unclear. Then, I am in a dilemma.

Comment: If you add a `catch` to the nested `try`, does that make Inspection happy?

Comment: You should extract the content of the whole `if` block to a new method. and give it a good name.

Comment: @bradimus sadly the inspection is still on due to multiple try, but adding a 'catch' does help when I extracted the content of the whole 'if' block to a new method according to Timothy Truckle solution

Comment: @Timothy Truckle it does help, thanks